# Can I get all of the terms and docId lists from ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

How can I get all of the terms and doc lists in ES.For example the inverted index data looks like the following:

```
word1: doc1,doc5,doc6...
word2: doc3,doc9,doc12...
word3: doc5,doc100...
```

I just wanna get all of the terms and correspond doc list. Any api I can do this. Thanks!

Comment: I'd try using this tool: https://simpsora.wordpress.com/2014/05/06/using-luke-with-elasticsearch/

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve this you should understand a little bit about how Lucene operates. In Lucene, the structure of the index is structured (as you seem to know) with Fields->Terms->PostingLists (represented as PostingsEnums).

To retrieve these values, you can use this as a template Lucene tool (assuming you have access to the base reader - `AtomicReader`:

```java
// get every one of the fields in the reader
Fields fields = MultiFields.getFields(reader);
for (String field: fields) {
    // get the Terms for the field
    TermsEnum terms = fields.terms(field).iterator(null);

    // a term is represented by a BytesRef in lucene
    // and we will iterate across all of them using
    // the TermsEnum syntax (read lucene docs for this)
    BytesRef t;
    while ((t = terms.next()) != null) {
        // get the PostingsEnum (not that this is called
        // DocsEnum in Lucene 4.X) which represents an enumeration
        // of all of the documents for the Term t
        PostingsEnum docs = terms.postings(null, null);
        String line = String.format("%s: ",t);
        while (docs.nextDoc() != NO_MORE_DOCS) {
            line += String.valueOf(docs.docID());
            line += ", "
        }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

I haven't actually had a chance to run this code exactly as is (I have a similar tool I've written for my specific fork of Lucene to compare Indexes), but hopefully this gives you the general knowledge of the structure of Lucene so that you can write your own tool.

The tricky part will be getting the explicit `AtomicReader` from your index - but I'm sure there are other StackOverflow answers to help you with that! (As a little hint you might want to look at opening your index with `DirectoryReader#open(File f)#leaves()`)